# Exception while trying to launch a Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, webview

I get an exception while trying to launch a flutter WebView. The exception i get is :

```
if (errorCode is String && (errorMessage == null || errorMessage is String) && !buffer.hasRemaining)
      throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage as String?, details: errorDetails, stacktrace: errorStacktrace);
    else
      throw const FormatException('Invalid envelope');
```

I tried to launch the Webview through a button click from my bottomNavigationBar. I created a different class with a widget which displays a webview. And i tried to call that class which holds the webview.

I will attach the entire code below for a better understanding. Thank you.

Entire Code :

```
class dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _dashboardState createState() => _dashboardState();
}

class Google extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(
            'Google',
          ),
        ),
        body: const WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://codeseasy.com",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _dashboardState extends State<dashboard> {
  int currentIndex = 1;

  changeIndex(index) {
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    if (index == 2) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => HomePage(),
        ),
      );
    }
    if (index == 0) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Google(),
        ),
      );
    }
    if (index == 1) {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => Notifications(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  final List<Widget> _children = [
    HomePage(),
    Notifications(),
    forgotPassword(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authService = Provider.of<AuthService>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, right: 250),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 20.0,
                  decoration:
                      BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                  child: (const Text(
                    'Hello',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 1.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 30.0),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomePage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 300.0, top: 5.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.notifications,
                  size: 25.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Notifications(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 390,
                  height: 450,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green.shade100,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        await authService.signOut();
      }),
      //  : _children[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        //  currentIndex: onTabTapped,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green[100],
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book_online),
            label: 'Google',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.read_more),
            label: 'Notifications',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Exception Screenshot :

[image: Screenshot of Exception]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried using Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement ? if not try navigate using pushReplacement instead of push

Comment: Yes, using  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement works, but then i can't navigate backwards when i use .pushReplacement. Any ways which i can navigate back from the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the package [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#usage)?

it literally says

> Usage
> Add webview_flutter as a dependency in your pubspec.yaml file. If you are targeting Android, make sure to read the Android Platform Views section below to choose the platform view mode that best suits your needs.

Long story short, you have to add this line in your `initState` function in `Google` class: `if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();`

Also you need to modify the `minSdkVersion` to 20 in `android/app/build.gradle`